# How can i put the icon on the top left inside of the image. Vue / CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2

i am working on a vue project and i am trying to make row of images with and icon on the top left inside each of the image.

this is my code:

```
<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index" class="d-inline py-5 ">
    <img :src="'/product_images/'+image.image_name" class="m-1 rounded-2 " alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
    <button class="btn"><i id="icon" class="bi bi-trash-fill text-danger" style="font-size: 22px"></i></button>
</div>
```

and this is what i get:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a vue specific requirement. It's just plain CSS.

You need to place your `button` ( the delete icon ) absolute relative to the wrapper ( that contains the image and button )

See below example

```css
.wrapper {
    position:relative
}
button {
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
   <button>
      Delete
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple way to do this is absolute positioning in CSS. This is an example with TailwindCSS (follow [this link](https://play.tailwindcss.com/MP6ALbZoHp) for reproduction):

```html
<div class="relative">
  <img src="/img/logo.svg" class="h-7 sm:h-8" />
  <div class="absolute top-0 left-0">Icon</div>
</div>
```

So your code should be adjusted to:

```html
<div v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index" class="d-inline py-5" style="position: relative">
    <img :src="'/product_images/'+image.image_name" class="m-1 rounded-2 " alt="" style="width: 100px; height: 100px">
    <button class="btn"><i id="icon" class="bi bi-trash-fill text-danger" style="font-size: 22px; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0"></i></button>
</div>
```

You can feel free to adjust the css properties `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` to fit your needs.

Comment: No, `z-index` only controls the z-axis level of the element. `z-index` is useful, if you want to place your `div` above the `image` in code.